# "looking-for-game" tag vs. "identify-this-game" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I think the [`looking-for-game`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-game) tag is excellent, but it's being used for two purposes right now. Some people are using it when they are looking for a game they remember details of but not the name of. It is also being used by people looking for games of a specific genre or setting, like "PS3 Games for Kids". I've seen the [`identify-this-game`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) tag and I think something like that should be used for the former purpose, and the `looking-for-game` tag should be used for the latter option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[identify-this-game]** very clearly establishes the purpose of the question is to identify a certain game. So I think it is much better suited towards questions that are identifying a game of unknown detail.

**[looking-for-game]** I'm a bit hesitant, if only because it really can be different between "I'm looking for *that* game where you..." versus "I'm looking for *a* game where you...". One word difference for two separate meanings. The former is game identification (clearly covered by [identify-this-game]), while the latter is game recommendation. So since the focus is on recommendations, I would personally recommend **[game-recommendations]**. It's a bit stuffier than [looking-for-game], but it's very explicit in what it means and unambiguous. Possibly, actually, just shorten it to **[recommendations]**, since it being about games can probably be implicit by this being a Gaming site.

On investigating for a retag, I noticed a **[games-rec]** tag is on a number of these. I think it would be wise to move these into a more concrete tag like **[recommendations]** or **[game-recommendations]**, because [games-rec] is really not very intuitive. I think it's possible to confuse this for, say, "recording", which also uses "rec" as a shorthand. So I think it would be wise to move those over as well. The presence of that tag is making me lean towards the longer tag [game-recommendation], because the redundancy isn't all that bad.

Comment: Sounds like great suggestion. Should I retag [looking-for-game] as [identify-this-game] and [recommendations]?

Comment: @Mew2468: I think I'm the one who started the [looking-for-game] tag, and I also fully support this. Please retag :)

Comment: Alright, I'm going to go with [game-recommendations]. It's not too bulky if you consider auto-complete, and I think the redundancy helps more than hurts (besides, we have [identify-this-_game_], anyway). And to me, the plural seems better.

Comment: I would say recommendations over game-recommendations, I don't see the point in the redundancy.

Comment: @Noctrine I really wanted to go with [recommendations]. But then I thought about recommendations for items that aren't games, like [peripherals](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243/where-can-i-get-a-good-arcade-joystick-for-the-xbox-360). As those are quite valid questions on the site, we can't really make some arbitrary ruling that a generic [recommendations] tag can *only* be applied to game recommendations.

Comment: How much more helpful would it be for there to be a recommendations tag for any possible occurrence over one generic one? It just seems like it would snowball into: RPG-recommendations racing-recommendations nintendo-recommendations sony-recommendations and whatever else.

Comment: @Noctrine I'm not suggesting we hit *every possible occurrence*, because all of those classify under [game-recommendations]. Comparatively, peripherals don't. We don't need a separate [rpg-recommendations] or [ps2-recommendations] from [game-recommendations], you can easily accomplish that with [rpg] [game-recommendations] or [ps2] [game-recommendations].

Comment: So why not, [peripheral] [recommendations]?

Comment: @Noctrine Because then we can't assume [recommendations] to be exclusive to gaming recommendations, which means that to allow people to filter all [recommendations] questions so that it's only about game recommendations, we need to use a [games] tag. Which I really don't think is useful to have on a website where the majority of content is going to be about games. It also brings another advantage, that [game-recommendations] only consumes one tag on the question.

Comment: Welp, then I agree.